# Export SQLQuery Result into another table

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Already tried some import command like into but getting error messages because script start with WITH:

I have the following script and like the outcome to be export to another table because of ssrs report slowing down.

```
WITH Calendar (Start_Date, End_Date) AS(
Select TOP 12
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, (SELECT DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()),0)))) -12 + Row_Number() Over (Order By CI_ID), 0)),0)[Start_Date],
DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, (SELECT DATEADD(s,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()),0)))) -12 + Row_Number() Over (Order By CI_ID), 0))+1,0)) [End_Date] 
From v_UpdateInfo
Group by CI_ID
)
Select Start_Date, End_Date,
(select count (distinct ucs.ResourceID) 
From v_Update_ComplianceStatus ucs
JOIN v_UpdateInfo ui on ui.CI_ID = ucs.CI_ID and ucs.Status = 2 AND ui.IsSuperseded = 0 and ui.IsEnabled=1 and ui.IsExpired=0
JOIN v_CICategoryInfo_All cica JOIN v_CategoryInfo ci on cica.CategoryInstanceID = ci.CategoryInstanceID AND cica.CategoryInstanceName = 'Critical Updates' on ucs.CI_ID = cica.CI_ID
Where ucs.ResourceID IN (Select sys.ResourceID from v_r_system sys JOIN v_UpdateScanStatus uss on uss.ResourceID = sys.ResourceID where Resource_Domain_OR_Workgr0 like '%NAM%' And DATEDIFF("d",uss.LastScanTime,getdate()) <= '30' AND sys.Obsolete0 = 0 and sys.Operating_System_Name_and0 like '%Workstation 6.1%') 
AND ui.DateRevised BETWEEN cal.Start_Date AND cal.End_Date
) [Windows_7]
from Calendar cal
```

Comment: Select * into newtable from currentable

Comment: If your SSRS report is slow and you're deploying it to a server, you might want to consider the 'Render this report from a report snapshot' option. You wouldn't need extra tables this way.

Comment: You may also want to consider optimising the query. To start I would take the query from your IN clause (WHERE ucs.ResourceID IN...) and dump the results into a temp table, then join to that temp table, you can then remove that part of the where clause. If the subquery in the IN clause returns a lot of records or is slow to execute, this will improve performance.